# Удалить < script >< script > из head шаблона Joomla?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla3

Здравствуйте!

```
<script type="application/json" class="joomla-script-options new">
{"csrf.token":"6284252a0f2c4d02dd5d7aaec3184011","system.paths":{"root":"","base":""}}
</script>
```

Как удалить из шаблона < script>< / script > на PHP ?
Подобный метод
$this->_script = $this->_scripts = array();
не удаляет

Comment: А если найти в шаблоне  и удалить полностью от туда?

Comment: То при обновление cms, тег вернется на место. У меня их 18 не очень хочется каждый месяц этим заниматься.

Comment: наверное, нужен встроенный js-скрипт, который будет каждый раз проверять наличие тега и удалять его?

Comment: Да, наверно. 
Есть же вариант отключения системных скриптов 
$headlink = $this->getHeadData();
unset($headlink['scripts']['/media/system/js/caption.js']);
$this->setHeadData($headlink);
А там вот такая строчка подключает
$buffer .= $tab . '<script type="application/json" class="joomla-script-options new">';
Какой кретин назвал его joomla-script-options new

Comment: [Посмотри](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215756/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-joomla)  Мою тему там все возможные способы. Но они тоже не сработали. Найдешь решение отпишись

Answer (score 0):

Формируется эта строчка в:

```
libraries/joomla/document/renderer/html/head.php
```

Но если удалить, скрипт не будет работать. Для начала нужно понимать, для чего она.

Например, когда надо будет вставить фото, то путь не пропишется.