# Как убрать атрибуты в стилях и скриптах Joomla?

Tags: php, css, html5, php7, joomla3

Друзья, Всем привет.
Ошибка валидатора. Перепробовал все, не исправляется. Ниже все случаи какие нашел в интернете.
Может кто имеет своё авторское решение?

> Warning: The type attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources.

```
From line 43, column 1; to line 43, column 112

endif]-->↩<script type="application/javascript" src="/media/plg_jchoptimize/cache/js/50af932736c592ec2b01f4474e8393c6.js"></scri
```

Вставить в начало index.php

```
    // Set HTML5 Document Output
$docHTML = JFactory::getDocument();
$docHTML->setHtml5(true);
```

Не сработало.
Дальше. В Includes.php

```
    <?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;



$app        = JFactory::getApplication();

$doc        = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->setHtml5(true);
$user   = JFactory::getUser();      // Add current user information
```

Не сработало валидатор выдает теже ошибки.
Так же нашел функцию которая должна удалить. Которую нужно поместить в function.php
Правда описания нет и какие параметры передавать и где вызывать не указано.

```
# удалить атрибут type у scripts и styles
// add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'sj_remove_type_attr', 10, 2);
// add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'sj_remove_type_attr', 10, 2);
// function sj_remove_type_attr($tag) {
//     return preg_replace( "/type=['\"]text\/(javascript|css)['\"]/", '', $tag );
// }
//
```